# Restore unity after removing gnome desktop (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, unity, gnome

I removed gnome desktop (ubuntu-gnome-desktop) to go back to unity but now the unity folder icons, unity panel icons and even the boot screen are as they were in the gnome desktop. Dash and launcher are there but icons are from gnome. How can I restore these?

I have tried resetting and reinstalling unity but it didn't work.

This is how folders and panel icons look like at present after removing Genome desktop and reinstalling unity.

[image: . This is how folders and panel icons look like at present after removing Genome desktop and reinstalling unity.]

Answer (score 2):

Reinstall the `ubuntu-desktop` package via command

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall `ubuntu-desktop`
```

If that doesn't help, you can manually reset icons and theme via Unity Tweak Tool, and use `update-alternatives` command to change plymouth theme ( that's the boot screen ) , like so:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth           
[sudo] password for xieerqi: 
There are 3 choices for the alternative default.plymouth (providing /lib/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth).

  Selection    Path                                                             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntukylin-logo/ubuntukylin-logo.plymouth   150       auto mode
  1            /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo-scale-2.plymouth     99        manual mode
  2            /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth             100       manual mode
  3            /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntukylin-logo/ubuntukylin-logo.plymouth   150       manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried reinstalling but it didn't change anything. Will try manually resetting icons. How can I restore boot screen?

Comment: @TeshanShanukaJ I've added that to my answer.  Well, themes also can be changed from Settings -> Appearance

Comment: thanks a lot. Boot screen is ok now. Anyway reinstalling ubuntu desktop didn't do any change. I've followed Rishi Shukla 's answer and managed to restore desktop icons. But couldn't reset panel icons. Also desktop right click menu is not appearing.  Seems like still there are leftovers from gnome desktop. These are the only things I've noticed far. Any suggestions?

Comment: @TeshanShanukaJ not sure about the right click menu. I've briefly looked through `gsettings` and configurations for `nautilus` which is what manages the desktop. From what you say , i get the sense that `nautilus` desktop window is running, since you see the icons. When it is not running, there is no right click. So i sense there's something about configurations that prevents displaying right click

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the icon and theme of unity in order to get back the default icon and panel settings ? If not try this.

**Install Unity Tweak Tool using PPA**

Open terminal and fire these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

First commands will add Unity Tweak Tool PPA and the third command will install unity Tweak Tool.

**Open installed Unity Tweak Tool from terminal or Dash**

To open the Unity Tweak Tool from terminal type

```
unity-tweak-tool
```

To open it from Dash simply search for it and then open it.

once opened you will be greeted with this screen.

[image: Unity Tweak Tool]

Now go in Theme and select *Ambiance*. After this go in Icons and select *unity-icon-theme*. Now your panel and icon will look like as they looked by default in Ubuntu.

Comment: That helped me restore desktop icons. Thanks a lot. But I couldn't reset panel icons. Selecting unity icon theme just made the current panel icons go gray (like disabled, but they are working). Default Ubuntu panel icons appear at login screen but they change to gnome icons when I login. Also desktop right click menu is not appearing. Seems like still there are leftovers from gnome desktop. These are the only things I've noticed far. Appreciate if you could help reset this. And why isn't gnome-desktop removed completely?

Comment: @TeshanShanukaJ Sorry, I couldn't be of much help after this as I'm also new to ubuntu . But just in case if i will come across any solution I will definitely let you now.